# Fade div in and out using the same link onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can fade a div in with a click but how do I use the same click to toggle that div, i.e. fade the div in on click and then fade the div out on second click.

I'd like navbar-toggle to be clicked once to open overlay and clicked again to fade out overlay.

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(e) {

  $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e){    
    $('.overlay, .popup').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e){         
    $('.overlay, .popup').fadeIn('slow');
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can u show your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it a couple of ways:

**Solution 1:**

Use `toggle()`

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e){    
    $('.overlay, .popup').toggle('fast');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zw6wfoa2/1/)**

**Solution 2:**

Use `fadeToggle()`

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e){    
    $('.overlay, .popup').fadeToggle(300);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zw6wfoa2/)**

**Solution 3:**

Have a hidden class and check to see if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Just use `toggle` and bind your element to one event handler:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e){    
    $('.overlay, .popup').toggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it also could be used like this,
by checking the current status of the element

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e){    
    if($('.overlay, .popup').css('display')=='none')
    {
        $(".overlay, .popup").fadeIn();           
    }
    else
    {
        $(".overlay, .popup").fadeOut();            
    }
});
```

Or by removing curly braces due to being in single line like this

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e){    
    if($('.overlay, .popup').css('display')=='none')
        $(".overlay, .popup").fadeIn();   
    else
        $(".overlay, .popup").fadeOut();    
});
```

Check out the fiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mfeb1px/8/)