# Overlay an image centered within image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am admittedly not the best with html/css, but this *seems* like it *should* be easy enough. However, I've spent an age googling and experimenting and still no dice. I'm trying to fade in an overlay of an image centered on another image on click (not hover). Which is kind of an awful sentence grammatically. 

What? Overlay an image.

Where? Over another image.

How? Centered, fade in/out.

When? On click.

I've been trying to combine code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp with no luck. I've tried toggle() based on [Fade div in and out using the same link onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245354/fade-div-in-and-out-using-the-same-link-onclick) but am clearly still doing something wrong.

This is what I have right now (and I'm sure it's a mess)
http://jsfiddle.net/xvdptw6L/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
/*.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}*/
.overlay {
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.ningenlife.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9/u/c/ucc-93553-3.jpg" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <img src="https://www.pokemoncenter.com/wcsstore/PokemonCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/products/P3486/701-02860/P3486_701-02860_01.jpg" class="overlay" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
$('.image').click(function(e){    
    $('.overlay').toggle('fast');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the commented out code is in play the second image fades in the way I want but when it's not the js does nothing. Please help me see where I'm going horribly wrong.

*answered perfectly below, just adding the w3schools and fiddle editors of the working version for copy/paste or an easy place to play with the code if anyone needs this solution in the future
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3T58QO5TYOY
http://jsfiddle.net/curfohwy/

Comment: P.S: A `script` tag cannot contain both the `src` attribute and the actual script code. Use two script tags. One for the `src` attribute and the other for your functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a class on click to the containing div and then you can manipulate the css to your liking like so:

```js
$('.container').click(function(e){    
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container.active .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container.active .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.ningenlife.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9/u/c/ucc-93553-3.jpg" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <img src="https://www.pokemoncenter.com/wcsstore/PokemonCatalogAssetStore/images/catalog/products/P3486/701-02860/P3486_701-02860_01.jpg" class="overlay" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```